# How to make a "trending" or "averaging" curve

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet on which I've been tracking my weight for the last year.

I weigh myself nearly every day, and I can be off by as much as 5 pounds from day to day.

I would like make a graph shows the overall pattern of my weight loss / gain, but without all of the noise.

What are some formulas that I can use to calculate the overall trend?

Comment: You could use a "moving average" where for each day you plot the average of that day's weight and the previous (eg) 4 days' measurements

Answer (score 0):

Place the raw daily measurements in **A1** thru **A365**
In **B2** enter:

```
=(A1+A2+A3)/3
```

and copy down.  Column **B** will give you a smoother dataset for plotting and trending.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have enough data points a "moving average" will help reduce the daily noise.   Let's say you have 10 data points starting in A1:

```
120.0   119.0   114.1   116.7   112.0   108.7   107.9   104.6   108.9   111.7
```

In cell `C2` you could use the formula `AVERAGE(A1:C1)` and copy it to the end of your data set.  THe relative references will always average the last 3 measurements.

Now your data looks like:

```
120.0   119.0   114.1   116.7   112.0   108.7   107.9   104.6   108.9   111.7
                117.7   116.6   114.3   112.5   109.5   107.1   107.1   108.4
```

So your second row has far less variation that the raw data.

You can also get fancy and make the number of measurements variable.  If that number were stored in A5 (below your data) then the formula would be something like

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C1,0,0,1,-MIN(COLUMN(),$A$5)))
```

The `MIN` ensures that you don't go past the beginning of the data set (if you do a 5-day moving average you can;t go back 5 days from the 4th day, etc.)